# Remove pattern in txt using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to remove a pattern from some text. I mean:

from `[1426467605000,19.44]` to `19.44`

Here is my input text file:

```
[1426467605000,19.44],[1426467965000,19.44],[1426468325000,19.38],[1426468685000,19.38],[1426469045000,19.38],[1426469405000,19.38],[1426469764000,19.38],[1426470124000,19.38],[1426470484000,19.38],[1426470845000,19.31],[1426471205000,19.31],[1426471565000,19.31],[1426471925000,19.31],[1426472285000,19.31],[1426472645000,19.31],[1426473005000,19.31],[1426473365000,19.31],[1426473725000,19.31],[1426474085000,19.31],[1426474445000,19.25],[1426474805000,19.25],[1426475164000,19.25],[1426475524000,19.25],[1426475884000,19.55],[1426476245000,19.25],[1426476605000,19.25],[1426476965000,19.25],[1426477325000,19.25],[1426477685000,19.19],[1426478045000,19.19],[1426478405000,19.19],[1426478764000,19.19],[1426479124000,19.19],[1426479484000,19.19],[1426479844000,19.19],[1426480204000,19.13],[1426480564000,19.13],[1426480924000,19.19],[1426481284000,19.19],[1426481644000,19.19],[1426482005000,19.19],[1426482365000,19.19],[1426482725000,19.19],
```

Here is my desired output:

```
19.44
19.44
19.38
19.38
19.38
etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

this grep line should do it:

```
grep -oP '[^,]*(?=])'
```

in short, this line extracts text between `,` and `]`, which are the things you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep` for that:

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file
```

The pattern searches for one or more numbers followed by a dot and again one or more numbers.

`-o` makes grep output the match only and the not the whole line where the match appears. `-E` allows us to use posix extended regular expression which saves us to escape the `+`.

---

An alternative would be to use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' RS='\\[|\\],|\\],\\[' file
```

This command performs a more semantic analysis, it returns the second value from a record. It separates records by `[` (start of line) or `],` or `],[`. It prints the second field of a record where fields are delimited by `,`.

If you want to allow that the last record of a line is closed without a `,` at the end you can simply modify the pattern to:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' RS='\\[|\\],?|\\],\\[' file
```

which makes the comma at the end of the record separator optional.

Comment: Will leave the last `]`

Comment: No, the output of both commands is the same and both are outputting just the numbers as expected - using the example data from the question.

Comment: Apologies, i hadn't seen the final comma, my bad

Comment: No problem. It isn't uncommon that a `,` will be appended to a list, this would make it a little easier to implement the writer..

Comment: @JID Have changed the awk command. Now it addresses your concerns.

Comment: You need to change `'$0=$2'` to `'{$0=$2}1'`.  If not it will fail if one of the value is  `0`

Comment: @Jotne Right! Changed it back to `{print $2}`.

Answer (score 2):

An `awk`alternative:

```
awk '$0~FS{print $1}' RS=',' FS=']' inputfile
```

`RS=','` : Changes **R**ecord **S**eparator to comma .

`FS=']'` : Set **F**ield **S**eparator to `]`.

`$0~FS` : If `FS` is present in the current record *print the first field* (avoid FS in the output)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep`.

```
$ grep -oP ',\K[^\]\[]*(?=\])' file
19.44
19.44
19.38
19.38
19.38
19.38
19.38
19.38
```

This regex would fetch the last string present inside the square brackets.

- `,` matches the first comma.
- `\K` discards the previously matched char comma.
- `[^\]\[]*` Negated character class which matches any character but not of `]` or `[`, zero or more times.
- `(?=\])` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a `]` character.

Answer (score 1):

sed

```
sed 's/\[[^,]\+,\([^]]\+\)\]/\1/g; s/,/\n/g'
```

The first regex looks for: a literal open bracket, some non-comma chars, a comma, capturing parenthesis, some non-close-bracket chars, end capture, and a literal close bracket. It replaces all of that with the captured text. Then, remaining commas are replaced by newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You could also go with sed and coreutils:

```
<infile tr -d '][' | tr , '\n' | sed '1d; n; d'
```

Output:

```
19.44
19.44
19.38
19.38
19.38
  .
  .
  .
```

#### Explanation

`tr` deletes the brackets and replaces comma with newline. `sed` then deletes the first line and every other line after that.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[]],[[\n]' -F, '{print $2}' file
19.44
19.44
19.38
19.38
```